# Detect connection protocol (HTTP/2, spdy) from javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to get the protocol that the browser used to get the active page?
Something like:

```
performance.navigation.protocol // e.g. "HTTP/2" or "SPDY/3.1" or "HTTP/1.1"
```

I know that it's possible to detect the protocol server side and then pass the info, but I'm looking for a JS solution.

(a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478628/how-to-detect-visitor-using-http-2-spdy) contains a broken link and no answer)

Comment: can you make a HEAD request to `location.href`with ajax? edit: nevermind, i don't see a response prop that would indicate it anyway...

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: ```performance.getEntries()[0].nextHopProtocol``` works in Chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is being [standardised](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing-2/) as `performance.timing.nextHopProtocol`, but chrome has a [non-standard implementation](http://www.tuanhuynh.com/blog/2015/measuring-first-paint-time-in-chrome/) already under `window.chrome.loadTimes().connectionInfo`:

```js
if ( window.performance && performance.timing.nextHopProtocol ) {
    console.log('Protocol:' + performance.timing.nextHopProtocol);
} else if (window.performance && window.performance.getEntries) {
    console.log(performance.getEntries()[0].nextHopProtocol);
} else if ( window.chrome && window.chrome.loadTimes ) {
    console.log('Protocol:' + window.chrome.loadTimes().connectionInfo);
} else {
    console.log("Browser does not expose connection protocol");
}
```